# Ubuntu WiFi fails to connect

Tags: wireless, networking, network-manager, 14.10

## ###Read Edits below###

#### initial post

I'm using 14.10 ubuntu and it is dual booted with windows 8.1, my issue occured "randomly" (being careful using that word - i dont remember if i did anything specific to cause the problem).

WiFi worked fine when i installed Ubuntu but recently when i try to connect to a network using either an (incorrect or correct) password, I am unable to successfully connect, after a certain amaount of time it asks for my credentials again and this process cycles. (Also i didnt install any drivers for wifi or bluetooth personally, it was setup on install) (bluetooth works)

I did once get a error message once saying Authentication failed could not connect but after restart it stopped showing.

I have tried to (0)google for similar problems (1) restart (2) sudo service network-manager restart (3)sudo service network-manager stop ...then... sudo service network-manager start (4) used the installer iso with try ubuntu to see if i can connect, this worked once but failed to work on other instances (5) scrapping all saved networks -> restart (6) creating new user then connecting

extra info: wifi is not softblocked or hardblocked.

I dont really know much about ubuntu (my first linux dist)

(also sorry if anything if not explained fully, if further info needed i will update/reply)

ok so ask requested:

#### iwconfig

```
eth0      no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=16 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

#### lspci

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200/2nd Generation Core Processor Family PCI Express Root Port (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev c4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev c4)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 6 (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM77 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile SATA Controller [RAID mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF108M [GeForce GT 630M] (rev a1)
08:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5229 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
0a:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 2230 (rev c4)
0b:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 07)
```

#### sudo lshw -C network

```
  *-network               
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Centrino Wireless-N 2230
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:0a:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: c4
       serial: 68:5d:43:78:76:cf
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=3.16.0-28-generic firmware=18.168.6.1 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       resources: irq:45 memory:d4500000-d4501fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:0b:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 07
       serial: a0:b3:cc:44:19:a1
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8168e-3_0.0.4 03/27/12 ip=192.168.0.20 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:44 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:d4404000-d4404fff memory:d4400000-d4403fff
```

#### OK so i've tested that my laptop works fine connecting to a mobile hotspot, so its having issues with my router, yet my router is fine also because many devices including my windows boot connect fine

is there any settings that could be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please share outputs of

```
iwconfig
lspci
lshw -C network
```

Try to connect ethernet cable and go System Settings > Software & Updates > Additional Drivers. There could be a driver for your wireless network interface.

- reboot your router, modem, or both

Because your router already had given a local IP for your MAC address while you were in Windows. Cause of that router thinks that this is a suspicious connection attempt. In the conclusion, just reboot your router.

Comment: Hi i have edited as requested and under the additional drivers tab there is no proprietary driver for wifi

Comment: Follow this tutorial: https://unixblogger.wordpress.com/2011/10/18/the-pain-of-an-realtek-rtl8111rtl8168-ethernet-card/

Comment: This didnt work =[

Comment: @VrushikPradip I realize that your problem is very simple just reboot your router.

Comment: can you explain the problem?

Comment: @VrushikPradip I explained above, in answer. I edited my answer.

Comment: so is there a permanent solution to this?

Comment: @VrushikPradip just unplug your modem(cut off the power) and plug  in again.

Answer (score 0):

if you are experiencing this problem check if your proxy servers are online. if one of your proxy servers are offline your internet will not work. i hope i helped you because i witnessed the same problem with my VM running ubuntu 14.04. i checked in my network settings and it said that one of my proxy servers were offline. i hope i helped you :P

Comment: wait im not trying to use a proxy server, which bit of info tells you that? i use a vpn on windows but i never have tried to do anything on ubuntu

Comment: if you were using a VPN on windows it all depends on how strong your internet connection is. your VPN can begin to slow down. it depends on what ver of windows ur running and your internet connection

Comment: if you try to use an internet browser it will say there is a problem with your proxy server and when this happened to me i fixed my proxy server and my computer (home built) runs good. i used to run windows but now im running ubuntu and my computer was slow on windows and my computer is fast now that im running ubuntu

Comment: wait, the problem is i cant connect to router at all, it just loops on auth

Comment: if this is the problem you need a new router bruh. if you are sad watch this video it will cheer you up ;> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-G_UEKMEjCw

Comment: our try to connect to ethernet

Comment: or use a internet cable

Comment: my router works fine, my windows can use the router fine along with many other devices

Comment: then i cant help you there should be nothing wrong with your internet or connecting to it so bye